# Matplotlib two X axis position switching

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I would like to make a plot having two X-axis.

But I would like to set the host x axis to top and the other x axis to bottom.

I tried:

```
    axs[i].barh(bins[:len(count_vol)], count_vol, align='edge', color='black', height = 10) # horizontal bar plot
    axs[i].set_xlabel('concentration (n/m3)')
    axs[i].set_ylabel('depth (m)')
    axs[i].invert_yaxis()
    axs[i].set_title(org, y =1.0) # subplot title
    axs[i].xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
    axs[i].xaxis.tick_top() # x axis to top of the subplot

    #plt.show()


    
    # add environmental data
    temp_ax = axs[i].twiny()
    temp_ax.plot(temperature, depth, color='red')
    temp_ax.set_xlabel('temperature', color='red')
    temp_ax.xaxis.tick_bottom() x axis to botton of the subplot
```

When I activatd 'plt.show()' the host x axis was on the top which I wanted to plot.
But after I ran whole script above, both x axis are on the bottom.

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Maybe you could call `axs[i].xaxis.tick_top()` after the creation of `twiny()`?

Comment: @JohanC Yes I tried. In that case, the tickes are moved with my intention, but the labels aren't moved. So ticks and labels are with the wrong position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to add an extra xaxis on top.

> ticks and labels are with the wrong position

I guess `temp_ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()` is rebundant.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.arange(10)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3)


# secondary axis

axs[0].plot(x)
axs[0].set_xlabel('label bottom')
secax = axs[0].secondary_xaxis('top')
secax.set_xlabel('label top')

# twiny()

axs[1].set_xlabel('label bottom')
twax = axs[1].twiny()
twax.set_xlabel('label top')


# handle properties

axs[2].xaxis.tick_top()
axs[2].xaxis.set_label_position('top')
axs[2].set_xlabel('label top')

plt.show()
```

[image]